# New rails 5.1 app using webpack, simply application.js won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have a brand new, default rails 5.1 application that I created.

I haven't touched any of the default files it created e.g. webpack.yml etc. so it is all default.

My /app/javascript/packs/application.js looks like this:

```
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
```

Now if I try and reference this file in one of my layouts:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

When I load the page, in chrome I can see a .js file load error:

> http://localhost:3000/packs/application-8d71e5035f8940a9e3d3.js 404
>   (Not Found)

I am not running any webpack-dev-server, I am just running the normal:

> rails s

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes, you need the webpack dev server `./bin/webpack-dev-server`

Comment: @Dimitry_N "This means that you don't have to run any separate processes. " from here https://github.com/rails/webpacker#webpack-configuration ??

Comment: as other suggest, sounds like your server isn't started or running... if that's not it maybe check this out http://blog.blackninjadojo.com/ruby/rails/2019/03/01/webpack-webpacker-and-modules-oh-my-how-to-add-javascript-to-ruby-on-rails.html has an example of basically using console.log in application.js

Answer (score 0):

As other developers said, you need a `./bin/webpack-dev-server` to hold something like

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
ENV["NODE_ENV"]  ||= "development"

require "pathname"
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

require "webpacker"
require "webpacker/dev_server_runner"
Webpacker::DevServerRunner.run(ARGV)
```

and at the same time you have your `rails s` running, you need to run `webpack-dev-server`  in a new terminal window. 
Every time you change something in the webpack configuration, restart it to update it.